# Android unable to return values from Firebase Datasnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

In here I need to get values form 'Firebase' node named as 'news_resources' to  'ArrayList'. 'INSIDE' Log is displaying the 'dataList1' size is 1, but 'OUTSIDE' 'Log' is displaying the 'dataList1' size is 0. Therefore 'fireBaseDataList' is null.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private static List<AppDataBean>fireBaseDataList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   fireBaseDataList = getDataFromFirebase("stringUrl");

}

private List<AppDataBean> getDataFromFirebase(final String url)
    {
        final ArrayList<AppDataBean>dataList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList1.clear();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("news_resources");

        reference.orderByChild("url").equalTo(url).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String country  = datas.child("country").getValue().toString();
                    String language = datas.child("language").getValue().toString();
                    String category = datas.child("category").getValue().toString();
                    String iconUrl = datas.child("iconUrl").getValue().toString();
                    String source = datas.child("source").getValue().toString();

                for(int i=0; i<datas.gretChildrenCount(); i++)
                {       
                    AppDataBean appDataBean = new AppDataBean();
                    appDataBean.setCountry(country);
                    appDataBean.setUrl(url);
                    appDataBean.setSource(source);
                    appDataBean.setIconUrl(iconUrl);
                    appDataBean.setLanguage(language);

                    dataList1.add(appDataBean);

                    Log.d("INSIDE","NEWS_RESOURCES_BEANS_ARE "+ dataList1.size() + ", " + appDataBean.getCountry() + ", " + appDataBean.getUrl()
                            + ", " + appDataBean.getSource()  + ", " + appDataBean.getIconUrl() + ", " + appDataBean.getLanguage());

                  }

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        Log.d("OUTSIDE", "FIREBASE_DATA_LIST_SIZE_IS " + dataList1.size());
        return dataList1;
    }
```

Comment: I searched more to find a solution, but finally got nothing.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Comment: OK. I agree with you. but in here I need to return an arrayList outside the onDataChange()

Comment: Then just use the second part of my answer from that post.

Comment: Without using void I need to use List<AppDataBean> for the method. Is it impossible? Any way thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's not.

Comment: I kindly appreciated for your comments and the post. I got that. Thankz

Comment: You're welcome, cheers!